# Word or phrase for people who spend a long time in each others company

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe two people who would have spent long periods of time together, to the point where they know each other's idiosyncrasies, would have many in-jokes, finish each other's sentences etc.

Comment: "duprass" , which, sadly, exists only for Vonnegut fans.

Comment: There's always "bromance".

Comment: Where and when do they spend this time? I've known guys at work who worked in the same bay for over a year and became good (work) friends. And they got to know each other pretty well. (*Sigh*)

Comment: *They frequent each other.* (Yes, it's a bit unusual to talk this way, I suppose.)

Answer (score 3):

Simpatico: "Being on the same wavelength," M-W

The word captures the idea of two or more people who are in tune with each other.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit old fashioned, but ***bosom buddies*** fits.

> One's close or closest friend; a friend one holds dear to one's heart.
>   *We grew up right next door to each other, so we have been **bosom buddies** since we were kids.*
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by FARLEX](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Bosom+Buddies)</sub>

A more modern (and informal) phrase would be ***brother from another mother***.

> These expressions don't refer to actual half-siblings. A brother from another mother is a friend that you feel as close to as if they were your actual brother.
>   <sub>[Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-the-expressions-brother-from-another-mother-and-sister-from-another-mister-refer-to-close-friends-rather-than-half-siblings)</sub>

Comment: Or just *buddies*.

Comment: @Clare: I lose the Tom Hanks vibe with just *buddies*.

Answer (score 0):

**Best mates**

> That one person in your life who is like a sibling. You'll do anything for them, literally. They understand you, you understand them and you're always happy when you're around them. You just click.
>
> Similar to best friend, but you can only really have one best mate, otherwise they are probably just good friends.

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=best%20mate)

Answer (score 0):

**[Old friends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPTOY8FrvNw)** are those who have had the time together to have had all those moments and formed all those jokes.

Answer (score 0):

You could describe people with this kind of relationship as being "thick as thieves."